# Отследить изменение DOM дерева после ajax запроса

Tags: ajax, dom

```
<div id='main'>

</div>

<ssript>
  $.ajax({
        url: "find",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "json",
   success:function(data) {
               $.each( data, function( key, value ) {
                         $("#main").append("<div class='card'> <img class='card-img-top' src=http://localhost/main/main/public/uploads/avatars/"+key+"><div class='card-block'><span class='nameUser'>"+ value+"</span></div></div>");
                        //alert( key + ": " + value );
                });


});

 $( ".nameUser" ).click(function() {
        PopUpShow();
    });

</script>
```

Как после ajax - запроса вызвать событие onclick на элементе,который появляется в dom уже после ajax запроса?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

через jquery ON - http://api.jquery.com/on/, http://jquery.page2page.ru/index.php5/On

```
$( document ).on( "click", ".nameUser", function() {
    PopUpShow();
});
```

Хотя вместо `document` в вашем случае скорее всего можно написать `#main`